# Calling template function within template class

Tags: c++, templates

Disclaimer: The following question probably is so easy that I might be shocked seeing the first answer. Furthermore, I want to apologize for any duplicate questions - syntactic problems are not always easy to identify be verbal explanation and thus searching for them is not as easy...

But enough of that. I have a two templated classes, one of those has a templated member function, the other class attempts to call that function. A minimal, error producing example is shown below:

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
class Foo {
public:
    Foo() {
    }

    template <typename outtype>
    inline outtype bar(int i, int j, int k = 1) {
        return k;
    }

};

template <typename T>
class Wrapper {
public:
    Wrapper() {
    }

    double returnValue() {
        Foo<T> obj;
        return obj.bar<double>(1,2); // This line is faulty.
    }

};

int main() {
    Wrapper<char> wr;
    double test = wr.returnValue();
    std::cout << test << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

At compile time, this results in

```
expected primary-expression before 'double'
expected ';' before 'double'
expected unqualified-id before '>' token
```

where all error messages are directed at the linke marked in the code.

I allready thank you for your ideas, no matter how obvious they are.

Comment: Explicit qualification is required because of its setting can not be deduced. Without template we get a syntax error, which will be perceived < as the operator is less than....See also language author point of view in "13.6. Stroustrup, spec. edition. 935-936."

Answer (score 62, accepted):

```
obj.bar<double>(1,2); // This line is faulty.
```

The `template` keyword is required here, as `obj` is an instance of a type `Foo<T>` which *depends on* the template parameter `T`, and so the above should be written as:

```
obj.template bar<double>(1,2); //This line is corrected :-)
```

Read @Johannes's answer here for detail explanation:

- [Where and why do I have to put the "template" and "typename" keywords?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-template-and-typename-on-dependent-names)

Answer (score 5):

As so often: Once the question was posted, the answer came all by itself.
Correcting the faulty line to

```
return obj.template bar<double>(1,2);
```

yields the expected results.

Thanks for reading...

Answer (score 3):

Could this be a case of `foo.template bar‹ double >`?