# function is ambiguous, which is not

Tags: c++, templates

I got `xxx is ambiguous` when I'm working on my c++ project. Since the whole project to too huge to upload in here, I made simple example which popup the same error message.

```
#include <string>
#include <memory>

namespace a {

template <typename T, typename Target>
inline std::shared_ptr<T> getShared(Target const& t)
{
    return std::static_pointer_cast<T>(t->shared_from_this());
}

class A : public std::enable_shared_from_this<A>
{
};

}

namespace b {

template <typename T, typename Target>
inline std::shared_ptr<T> getShared(Target const& t)
{
    return std::static_pointer_cast<T>(t->shared_from_this());
}

class A : public std::enable_shared_from_this<A>
{
};

void invoke()
{
    // ERROR OCCURED!!!
    a::A* a;
    getShared<a::A>(a);

    // But this is compiled without any problem :(
    //  A* a;
    //  getShared<A>(a);
}

}

int main(int, char**)
{
    b::invoke();

    return 0;
}
```

And here's the error message...

```
clang++ -c -pipe -g -std=gnu++1y -Wall -W -fPIC -DQT_QML_DEBUG -I../untitled -I. -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/mkspecs/linux-clang -o main.o ../untitled/main.cpp
../untitled/main.cpp:34:2: error: call to 'getShared' is ambiguous
        getShared<a::A>(a);
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../untitled/main.cpp:7:27: note: candidate function [with T = a::A, Target = a::A *]
inline std::shared_ptr<T> getShared(Target const& t)
                          ^
../untitled/main.cpp:21:27: note: candidate function [with T = a::A, Target = a::A *]
inline std::shared_ptr<T> getShared(Target const& t)
```

I tried with both gcc 6.3.0 and clang 3.8.1-24, and both compilers gave me the same error.

Could somebody let me know what is wrong in this code?

Comment: You need to read about [ADL](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl).

Comment: Upvoted for reduction to minimal example.

Comment: @miradulo: close, but this has at least two differences: `template` and sibling namespaces.

Comment: @MSalters Fair enough, agreed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The comments basically answer the question, but let's wrap it all up.

The compiler's first challenge is to parse `getShared<a::A>(a);`. Now this could be `operator<` and `operator>`, but the compiler [first looks up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35391324/how-does-a-parser-for-c-differentiate-between-comparisons-and-template-instant) `getShared` and notices it's a template, so the `<a::A>` is the template argument list.

It's also a function template, so `a` is a function argument. At this point, something complex happens. Since `a` has type `a::A*`, it has an *associated namespace* . The compiler does a **new** name lookup of `getShared`, now that it knows it's a function with an argument and an associated namespace. This **second** lookup also finds `a::getShared`. That is also a function template, and it can be instantiated with `<a::A>`. (SFINAE could exclude it, but the argument is OK).

You now have two instantiations, and overload resolution doesn't resolve their ambiguity.

The name of this second lookup is *Argument Dependent Lookup*, as mentioned by miradulo.