# What does a parser for C++ do until it can differentiate between comparisons and template instantiations?

Tags: c++, parsing, gcc, compiler-construction, clang

After reading [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35391324/how-does-a-parser-for-c-differentiate-between-comparisons-and-template-instant) I am left wondering what happens (regarding the AST) when major C++ compilers parse code like this:

```
struct foo 
{
  void method() { a<b>c; }

  // a b c may be declared here
};
```

Do they handle it like a GLR parser would or in a different way? What other ways are there to parse this and similar cases?

For example, I think it's possible to postpone parsing the body of the method until the whole struct has been parsed, but is this really possible and practical?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although it is certainly possible to use GLR techniques to parse C++ (see a number of answers by [Ira Baxter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/120163/ira-baxter)), I believe that the approach commonly used in commonly-used compilers such as gcc and clang is precisely that of deferring the parse of function bodies until the class definition is complete. (Since C++ source code passes through a preprocessor before being parsed, the parser works on streams of tokens and that is what must be saved in order to reparse the function body. I don't believe that it is feasible to reparse the source code.)

It's easy to know when a function definition is complete, since braces (`{}`) must balance even if it is not known how angle brackets nest.

C++ is not the only language in which it is useful to defer parsing until declarations have been handled. For example, a language which allows users to define new operators with different precedences would require all expressions to be (re-)parsed once the names and precedences of operators are known. A more pathological example is COBOL, in which the precedence of `OR` in `a = b OR c` depends on whether `c` is an integer (`a` is equal to one of `b` or `c`) or a boolean (`a` is equal to `b` or `c` is true). Whether designing languages in this manner is a good idea is another question.

Comment: Very informative answer, though it could use some reference(s) about gcc/clang deferring the parse.

Comment: @panoskj: both compilers are open source; you can read the code yourself. I'm not going to do a full description of the parsing code here, particularly since I haven't looked at them in a while.

Comment: @rici: it wasn't clear you have read gcc/clang code, in which case I'll take your word for it.

Answer (score 2):

The answer will obviously depend on the compiler, but the article [How Clang handles the type / variable name ambiguity of C/C++](https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2012/07/05/how-clang-handles-the-type-variable-name-ambiguity-of-cc) by Eli Bendersky explains how Clang does it. I will simply note some key points from the article:

- Clang has no need for a lexer hack: the information goes in a single direction from lexer to parser
- Clang knows when an identifier is a type by using a symbol table
- C++ requires declarations to be visible throughout the class, even in code that appears before it
- Clang gets around this by doing a full parsing/semantic analysis of the declaration, but leaving the definition for later; in other words, it's lexed but parsed after all the declared types are available

Comment: "Clang has no need for a lexer hack".   OK, so that's an improvement over having a lexer hack, but it sounds from your description  like they replaced with it with a correspondingly icky parser hack.   One man's opinion.

Comment: Although I accepted another answer, because it is more complete on its own, the article you provided is really insightful and I recommend reading it.