# Template member function call -- "error: expected primary-expression before 'int'"

Tags: c++, c++11

I am trying to test below code but getting compile error:

> TemplateTest.cpp:44:13: error:expected primary-expression before 'int'
>           h_.handle<int>(i);

build command:

> **g++ -c -std=c++11 -g -O2 -Wall -Werror   TemplateTest.cpp -o TemplateTest.o**

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

enum PROTOCOL {
  PROTO_A,
  PROTO_B
};

// ----- HandlerClass -------
template <PROTOCOL protocol>
class Handler {
public:
    template <class TMsg>
    bool handle(const TMsg&) {
        return false;
    }
};

template <>
template <class TMsg>
bool Handler<PROTO_A>::handle(const TMsg&) {
    cout << "PROTO_A handler" << endl;
    return true;
}

template <>
template <class TMsg>
bool Handler<PROTO_B>::handle(const TMsg&) {
    cout << "PROTO_B handler" << endl;
    return true;
}

// ----- DataClass ------
template <PROTOCOL protocol>
struct Data {
    typedef Handler<protocol> H; //select appropriate handler
    H h_;
    int i;
    Data() : i() {}

    void f() {
            h_.handle<int>(i); //***** <- getting error here
    }
};

int main () {
    Data<PROTO_A> b;
    b.f();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: inside a `template` to call another template one need `template` clause. In your particular example: `h_.template handle<int>(i);`

Comment: THANKS W.F. This worked. :) . but Why? could you point me to some related references

Comment: actually this is due to the fact compiler cannot establish if the "<" character is the less operator or if it is a start of a template invocation... see related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7397934/calling-template-function-within-template-class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below line is incorrect:

`h_.handle<int>(i);`

Since `h_` is an instance of a template class `Handler<PROTOCOL>`.

Change it to:

`h_.template handle<int>(i);`

You should checkout answer to the below SO question:

[Where and why do I have to put the "template" and "typename" keywords?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords)